How to prove the statement for any real number $x$, $x^3-x>0$ iff $-1<x<0$ or $x>1$. Stuck on forwards implication
The current problem I am working on is from the book An Introduction to Mathematical Proofs by Nicholas A. Loehr. What follows is the problem statement and my work; I am currently stuck on the forward implication and need help.
Exercise 2.6. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \left[ \left( x^{3}-x>0 \right) \iff \left( (-1<x<0) \lor (x>1) \right) \right]$
I found this related question, but I am not sure how to implement it in my own solution.

As I said, I need help with the forward implication, but I'll give my proof of the backwards implication in case someone wants to review it.
$\left( \Longleftarrow\right)$ Fix $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$. There are two cases, and we treat the former first, but we prove $x_{0}^{3}-x_{0}=x_{0}\left( x_{0}-1 \right)\left( x_{0}+1 \right)>0$ in both. In the first case, we assume $-1<x_{0}<0$, so both $x_{0}$ and $x_{0}-1$ are negative, while $x_{0}+1$ is positive. The product of two negatives is positive, and the product of two positives is positive, so $x_{0}^{3}-x_{0}>0$. In the second case, suppose $x>1$. Then, similarly, $x_{0}+1$ is positive, but this time, $x_{0}$ and $x_{0}-1$ are both positive, too. Thus, $x_{0}^{3}-x_{0}>0$, as desired.
Here is the meat of my troubles:
$\left( \Longrightarrow \right)$ Fix $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$. I think I can prove this in the contrapositive, but I am stuck with denying the would-be antecedent here:
$$ \begin{align}
\neg \left[ \left( (-1<x_{0})\land (x_{0}<0) \right) \lor \left( x_{0}>1 \right)  \right]  & \equiv \neg\left[ (-1<x_{0})\land (x_{0}<0) \right] \land \neg \left[x_{0}>1 \right] \\
 & \equiv \left[ (-1\geq x_{0}) \lor (x_{0} \geq0) \right] \land  \left[ x_{0}\leq 1 \right] \\
 & \equiv \left[ (x_{0}\leq-1) \land (x_{0} \leq 1) \right] \lor \left[ (0\leq x_{0})\land (x_{0} \leq 1) \right]   \\
\end{align} $$
Specifically, I am not sure what to make of the statement $[(x_{0}\leq-1) \land (x_{0} \leq 1)]$. I know if $x_{0}\leq-1$, then $x_{0} \leq 1$, but I do not know what to think of the converse. Any help would be nice.

Usually we proceed by cases and using the sign property for product. Are you looking for something different?

@user I think I'm just struggling with the OR statements wrapped within the AND statements, and vice-versa. If I'm understanding the problem correctly, I would need to prove 6 different cases, yes?

I remember my teacher making sign tables for functions in freshman calculus. It is start of fall semester, so let me make the sign table (method) for $f(x)=x^3-x$ and her memory:
$$f(x)=x(x^2-1)=x(x-1)(x+1)$$
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&&-1&&0&&1&\\\hline
x&-&-&-&0&+&+&+\\\hline
x-1&-&-&-&-&-&0&+\\\hline
x+1&-&0&+&+&+&+&+\\\hline
f(x)&-&0&+&0&-&0&+\\\hline
\end{array}$$
The solution set is
$$S=\{x|f(x)>0\}=\{x|-1<x<0 \lor x>1\}.$$
which also can be shown in interval notaions as
$$S=(-1,0)\cup(1,\infty).$$
So, the proposition of Exercise 2.6. is true.

Consider this :
$$\implies$$
$x^3-x > 0 \implies x(x^2-1) > 0$
$x^3-x > 0 \implies \color{orange}{\{ [ x > 0 ] \land [ (x^2-1) > 0 ] \}} \lor \color{purple}{\{ [ x < 0 ] \land [ (x^2-1) < 0 ] \}}$
$x^3-x > 0 \implies \color{orange}{\{ [ x > 0 ] \land [ x^2 > 1 ] \}} \lor \color{purple}{\{ [ x < 0 ] \land [ x^2 < 1 ] \}}$
$x^3-x > 0 \implies \color{orange}{\{ [ x > 0 ] \land [ x > 1 \lor x < -1 ] \}} \lor \color{purple}{\{ [ x < 0 ] \land [ x^2 < 1 ] \}}$
$x^3-x > 0 \implies \color{orange}{\{ [ x > 1 ] \}} \lor \color{purple}{\{ [ x < 0 ] \land [ -1 < x < 1 ] \}}$
$$x^3-x > 0 \implies \color{orange}{\{ [ x > 1 ] \}} \lor \color{purple}{\{ [ -1 < x < 0 ] \}}$$
$$\impliedby$$
I am skipping Details , let me know whether you can complete it or not.
Show this : $[ x > 1 ] \implies x^3-x > 0$
Show this : $[ -1 < x < 0 ] \implies x^3-x > 0$
Conclude this : $$\{ [ x > 1 ] \} \lor \{ [ -1 < x < 0 ] \} \implies x^3-x > 0$$

Thank you for this response, it set me on the right path, I think. Hopefully you can look at my answer and give me some feedback!

As noticed we usually proceed by cases and since $x^3-x=x(x^2-1)$ with roots at $x=-1,0,1$, we have $x(x^2-1)>0$ in $2$ cases (that is $1\lor 2$):

$x>0 \land x^2-1>0 \implies x>1$

$x<0 \land x^2-1<0 \implies -1<x<0$


therefore
$$x(x^2-1)>0\implies \left(-1<x<0 \lor x>1\right)$$
that is $x\in(-1,0)\cup(1,\infty)$.

this response was really helpful :) I tried proving it on my own, though, or filling in the blanks, I guess. Thanks for the help; hopefully you could share your thoughts on my own answer above!



Exercise 2.6. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \left[ \left( x^{3}-x>0 \right) \iff \left( (-1<x<0) \lor (x>1) \right) \right]$

Here is the meat of my troubles:
$\left( \Longrightarrow \right)$ Fix $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$. I think I can prove this in the contrapositive
$$ \begin{align}
&\neg \left[ \left( (-1<x_{0})\land (x_{0}<0) \right) \lor \left( x_{0}>1 \right)  \right]  \\& \color\red\equiv \neg\left[ (-1<x_{0})\land (x_{0}<0) \right] \land \neg \left[x_{0}>1 \right] \\
 & \color\red\equiv \left[ (-1\geq x_{0}) \lor (x_{0} \geq0) \right] \land  \left[ x_{0}\leq 1 \right] \\
 & \color\red\equiv \left[ (x_{0}\leq-1) \land (x_{0} \leq 1) \right] \lor \left[ (0\leq x_{0})\land (x_{0} \leq 1) \right]   \\
\end{align} $$
Specifically, I am not sure what to make of the statement $[(x_{0}\leq-1) \land (x_{0} \leq 1)]$. I know if $x_{0}\leq-1$, then $x_{0} \leq 1$, but I do not know what to think of the converse.

Those ≡ symbols are asserting bi-implication, indicating that you are forgetting that in this section of your proof you're merely proving the forward direction. Replace those symbols with ⟹ (furthermore, it's unnecessary to consider any converse). Then, continuing:
$$\left[ (x_{0}\leq-1) \land (x_{0} \leq 1) \right] \lor \left[ (0\leq x_{0})\land (x_{0} \leq 1) \right] \\
\implies x_0\leq-1\quad\lor\quad 0\leq x_0\leq1\\
\implies x(x^2-1)\leq0\\
\implies x^3-x\not>0,
$$
as required!
P.S. The table in Bob Dobb's answer elaborates on the second-from-last step above.

A generalized visual method to solve such inequalities involving rational functions is to plot the zeroes of the given function(here, $x^3-x$) on the number line(which represents the values $x$ can take):

Hence, we have $4$ intervals of $x$. Since the leading coefficient of $x^3-x$ is positive, mark the rightmost interval with a $+$ sign, as $x>1, 0, -1\implies (x+1)x(x-1)>0$. Then, go from right to left, switching signs when a number is encountered whose corresponding factor in the given function is raised to an odd power(here, all the factors: $(x-1)$, $(x)$ and $(x+1)$ are raised to the power $1$), as the sign of that factor will change depending on whether $x$ is greater than or less than its zero only if its power is odd(if it’s even, the value of the factor will always be non-negative).

This immediately yields the solution for $x^3-x>0$ as $-1<x<0\cup x>1$ or in interval form as $x\in(-1,0)\cup(1,\infty)$.

I came up with an answer that is a little different from the given ones, so I thought I would share it. The text instructs us to apply a specific approach to certain statements, but my main issue with the forward implication was that I wasn’t connecting my assumptions. Another issue was the somewhat unusual approach to proving OR-statements suggested by the text, which I hadn’t seen before and will discuss below.

Statement to prove: If $x^{3}-x>0$, then $-1<x<0$ or $x>1$.
Proof. Fix $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Assume $x_0\left(x_0^2-1\right)>0$, which leads to two cases: either $x_0>0$ and $x_0^2-1>0$, or $x_0<0$ and $x_0^2-1<0$. For the former case, we assume $0 \leq x_0$ or $x_{0}\leq -1$, to prove that $x_0>1$ (this is the "odd" approach I referenced above, which I will discuss below). In the cases where $x_0=-1$, $x_0=0$, or $x_0<-1$, this contradicts our earlier assumption that $x_0>0$, so these cases are ignored. Rewriting our assumption $x_0^2-1>0$ as $x_0^2>1$ and taking the square root of both sides, we get $x_0>1$ or $x_0<-1$. Since $x_0>0$, we ignore $x_0<-1$, and it follows that $x_0>1$.
In the latter case, we assume $x_0<0$ and $x_0^2-1<0$, or $x_0^2<1$. Here, we assume $x_0 \leq 1$, and we must prove that $-1<x_0<0$. Since we assumed $x_0<0$, it follows that $x_0 \leq 1$ must hold. Thus, taking the square root of both sides of $x_0^2<1$, we obtain $-1<x_0<1$. However, since we have assumed $x_0<0$, this simplifies to $-1<x_0<0$.$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

The "odd" approach I mentioned suggests proving an OR-statement by assuming the negation of one disjunct and proving the other. The justification, though, is that $P \vee Q \equiv$ $(\neg P) \Longrightarrow Q \equiv(\neg Q) \Longrightarrow P$, which makes sense? Another unusual aspect is that this method only works if certain statements take precedence, I think, such as $x_0<0$ or $x_0>0$. Hopefully someone can chime in here, I would appreciate an explanation on this. In any case, here's a sketch/outline of the entire proof using this method, if needed:

Statement to prove: $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \left[ \left( x^{3}-x>0 \right) \iff \left( (-1<x<0) \lor (x>1) \right) \right]$.
Let $x_0$ be a fixed, but arbitrary real number.

Part 1. If $x_0^{3}-x_0>0$, then $-1<x_0<0$ or $x_0>1$.

Case 1. Assume $x_0>0$ and $x_0^{2}-1>0$. Prove $-1<x_0<0$ or $x_0>1$.

Assume $\neg \left( -1<x_0 <0 \right)\equiv \left[ (-1\geq x_0) \lor (x_0\geq 0) \right]$. Prove $x_0>1$.


Case 2. Assume $x_0<0$ and $x_0^{2}-1<0$. Prove $-1<x_0<0$ or $x_0>1$.

Assume $\neg \left( x_0>1 \right)\equiv x_0\leq 1$. Prove $-1<x_0<0$.




Part 2. If $-1<x_0<0$ or $x_0>1$, then $x_0^{3}-x_0>0$.

Case 1. Assume $-1<x_0<0$. Prove $x_0^{3}-x_0>0$.
Case 2. Assume $x_0>1$. Prove $x_0^{3}-x_0>0$.





